# which scaling factors are supported in UWP?

Tags: uwp

According to this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt210779.aspx : 
"Windows 10 provides three user interface scaling factors: 1.0x, 1.4x, and 1.8x. Scaling values for each display are set during installation based on a number of combined factors: the size of the screen, the resolution of the screen, and the assumed average distance of the user from the screen"

so why it doesn't support for scale-200? because in asset folder for tiles and logo it support these scale factoring. I mean if I use _scale-400 or ..., it supports it or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 10 supports 100%, 125%, 150%, 200%, 400% scale factor for assets. You can find more details here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt412102.aspx

Comment: Seems like that link refers to packaging DirectX games, not apps.